# Creating a byte (8 bits) from 4 2 bits

Tags: c, algorithm, binary, spi, dma

I am trying to figure out a way to get as much out of the limited memory in my microcontroller (32kb) and am seeking suggestions or pointers to an algorithm that performs what I am attempting to do.

**Some background:** I am sending Manchester Encoded bits out a SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface) directly from DMA. As the smallest possible unit I can store data into DMA is a byte (8 bits), I am having to represent my 1's as 0b11110000 and my 0's as 0b00001111. This basically means that for every bit of information, I need to use a byte (8 bits) of memory. Which is very inefficient.

If I could reduce this, so that my 1's are represented as 0b10 and my 0's as 0b01, I'd only have to use a 1/4 of a byte (2 bits) for every 1 bit of memory, which is fine for my solution.

Now, if I could save to DMA in bits, this would not be a problem, but of course I need to work with bytes. So I know the solution to my problem involves collecting the 8 bits (or in my case, 4 2bits) and then storing to DMA as a byte.

**Questions:**

Is there a standard way to solve this problem?

How can I some how create a 8 bit number from a collection of 4 2 bit numbers? But I do not want the addition of these numbers, but the actual way it looks when collected together.

**For example:** I have the following 4 2 bit numbers (keeping in mind that 0b10 represents 1 and 0b01 represents 0) (Also, the type these are stored in is open to the solution, as obviously there is no such thing as a 2 bit type)

**Number1:** 0b01  **Number 2:** 0b10  **Number 3:** 0b10  **Number4:** 0b01

And I want to create the following 8 bit number from these:

**8 Bit Number:** 0b01 10 10 01 or without the spaces 0b01101001 (0x69)

I am programming in c

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can pack four numbers `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, all of which of value zero or one, like so:

```
64 * (a + 1) + 16 * (b + 1) + 4 * (c + 1) + (d + 1)
```

This is using the fact that `x + 1` encodes your two-bit integer: 1 becomes 0b10, and 0 becomes 0b01.

Comment: I feel like a bit-shift implementation would be more clear: `(a + 1)<<6 + (b + 1)<<4 + (c + 1)<<2 + (d + 1)`

Comment: How did you answer this question so quickly? Amazed and thankful, you may have just helped me reduce my memory usage by a factor of 4!

Comment: Thanks Macattack, feel free to add this as an answer, and which ever one I use I will aware the tick. Apologies Kerrek, I jumped the gun on the tick...but still impressed with your speed!

Comment: Great, but you can go one better!  Do all the additions in parallel: `((((a << 2) | b) << 2) | c) << 2) | d) + 0x55`  Shifting by only 2 each time runs faster if the processor doesn't have a barrel shifter.

Answer (score 1):

It's Manchester encoding so 0b11110000 and 0b00001111 should be the *only* candidates.  If so, then reduce the memory by a factor of 8.

```
uint8_t PackedByte = 0;
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
  PackedByte <<= 1;
  if (buf[i] == 0xF0) //  0b11110000
    PackedByte++;
}
```

Other other hand, if it's Manchester encoding and one may not have *perfect* encoding, then there are 3 results: 0, 1, indeterminate.

```
uint8_t PackedByte = 0;
for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
  int upper = BitCount(buf[i] >> 4);
  int lower = BitCount(buf[i] & 0xF);
  if (upper > lower)
    PackedByte++;
  else if (upper == lower)
    Hande_Indeterminate();
}
```

Various simplifications absent in the above, but shown for logic flow.

Comment: Hi Chux, not sure I understand how this works, since I need a rising edge to represent 0 and a falling edge to represent 1. How do I represent this with 1 bit with Manchester encoding?

Comment: @Remixed123 Excuse me.  My answer is focused on receiving rather than transmitting.  I still think you can use 1 packed bit to instruct the SPI's next 8 bits, as  0b11110000 or ob00001111.  The larger challenge is in reading the SPI with the idea the data in Manchester encoded.  You are doing a 4x oversample on sending.  If you are also receiving likewise, this answer may help.

Comment: That would be great if I could use 1 bit to instruct my SPI's next eight bits. Not sure that my microcontroller has that level of SPI configurability. Does this feature have a name? That way I can search on it in the data sheet for my microcontroller. Regarding the receiving end, this is a bunch of (up to 2048) individually self addressed integrated circuits. They each take a portion of the packet and pass the rest on.

Comment: No. What I suggest to send is that in your buffer of _data_ to send, you extract 1 bit at a time and then send to the SPI an 8-bit byte of 0b11110000 or 0b00001111.  If you can not tell the SPI 8-bits at a time, set up a local buffer of 8 and each time you need to send a bit, pull from there, replenishing that 8-bit buffer with 0b11110000 or 0b00001111 as needed based on the next bit from the _data_ buffer.

Comment: Ok, actually that's an interesting approach. I'd need to see if the data can be sent without breaking the communication or timing in anyway. Might be possible to get timing right by setting up a timer, but getting it to send in one constant stream without any breaks might be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

To number get abcd from (a,b,c,d) you need to shift the number to their places and OR :-

> (a<<6)|(b<<4)|(c<<2)|d